# Version problem with loading parquet file to AWS Redshift/Redshift Spectrum but not AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, spectrum

Using Redshift Spectrum to read the parquet exported from CDC (Or even using copy command of Redshift to load) get error: 
unsupported version. file version: 2

```
[500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
Details:
-----------------------------------------------
error: S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
code: 15001
context: Task failed due to an internal error. File: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/categories/LOAD00000001.parquet is of an unsupported version. file version: 2

query: 4253727
location: dory_util.cpp:1119
process: fetchtask_thread [pid=25020]
```

However, using AWS Athena still OK. 
So how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Seems related: [AWS Developer Forums: Redshift Spectrum : Getting no values/ ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=274957)

Comment: Hello, it is not a corrupt file as we can still query with Athena